# How do I narrow down my numeric data in my column to only even values?

Tags: postgresql

The data in my column is numeric and I want to permanently change the numeric data to only contain even values.
For example if I have the data in the column as 101331, 107332, 101333, 101334 I only want the updated table to contain 107332 and 101334.

| Original Column | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| 101331 | 107332 |
| 107332 | 101334 |
| 101333 |  |
| 101334 |  |

Comment: Use the modulus: `WHERE num % 2 = 2` ... for even numbers

Comment: Can you show me a demo? because my data ranges in the millions and I only want to select all the even data and remove all the odd ones

Comment: `update table set ... where num % 2 = 0` ?

Comment: 1) Databases do not have cells. 2) What do you want to do with the odd numbers? To your question add example of existing data and example of what you want the final output to be? Something more then what you have now.

Comment: Both strategies still end up showing odd numbers in my model... Is this correct?